# Mongodb aggregation in two dimensions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection like this. Huge amount of data, ~ 8 GB

```
> db.collector.find({},{'first':1,srcport: true,dstport:true,dOctets:true,_id:0}).skip(1682000)
{ "dstport" : 34760, "dOctets" : 104, "first" : NumberLong("1476941688344"), "srcport" : 443 }
{ "dstport" : 443, "dOctets" : 104, "first" : NumberLong("1476941689944"), "srcport" : 59326 }
{ "dstport" : 59326, "dOctets" : 104, "first" : NumberLong("1476941690034"), "srcport" : 443 }
{ "dstport" : 5222, "dOctets" : 164, "first" : NumberLong("1476941698934"), "srcport" : 58918 }
{ "dstport" : 443, "dOctets" : 92, "first" : NumberLong("1476941698974"), "srcport" : 42704 }
{ "dstport" : 443, "dOctets" : 116, "first" : NumberLong("1476941698974"), "srcport" : 34716 }
{ "dstport" : 34716, "dOctets" : 104, "first" : NumberLong("1476941698984"), "srcport" : 443 }
{ "dstport" : 42704, "dOctets" : 80, "first" : NumberLong("1476941698984"), "srcport" : 443 }
{ "dstport" : 58918, "dOctets" : 104, "first" : NumberLong("1476941699024"), "srcport" : 5222 }
{ "dstport" : 123, "dOctets" : 152, "first" : NumberLong("1476941699244"), "srcport" : 123 }
{ "dstport" : 123, "dOctets" : 152, "first" : NumberLong("1476941699294"), "srcport" : 123 }
{ "dstport" : 54526, "dOctets" : 394, "first" : NumberLong("1476941700394"), "srcport" : 3389 }
{ "dstport" : 3389, "dOctets" : 104, "first" : NumberLong("1476941700394"), "srcport" : 54526 }
{ "dstport" : 123, "dOctets" : 152, "first" : NumberLong("1476941701254"), "srcport" : 123 }
{ "dstport" : 5678, "dOctets" : 402, "first" : NumberLong("1476941703414"), "srcport" : 39926 }
{ "dstport" : 5678, "dOctets" : 268, "first" : NumberLong("1476941703414"), "srcport" : 39926 }
{ "dstport" : 5678, "dOctets" : 399, "first" : NumberLong("1476941703414"), "srcport" : 46336 }
{ "dstport" : 5678, "dOctets" : 266, "first" : NumberLong("1476941703414"), "srcport" : 46336 }
{ "dstport" : 5678, "dOctets" : 381, "first" : NumberLong("1476941703414"), "srcport" : 46575 }
{ "dstport" : 5678, "dOctets" : 387, "first" : NumberLong("1476941703414"), "srcport" : 46845 }
```

I want do take top statistics.

0)match

```
{'$match': {
                    first: {
                     '$gte':startdate,
                     '$lte':stopdate},
                }}
```

1) group by `dstport` and sum `dOctets`

```
'$group': {_id: { port:"$dstport"...
```

2) group by `srcport` and sum `dOctets`

```
'$group': {_id: { port:"$srcport"...
```

3) join 1,2 groups

4) group by `_id.port` and sum sums

5) sort and limit

Result i want must looks like

```
[{port:443, inOctets:123456, outOctets:321654, sum: 445110}...
```

I tried with aggregation pipeline, but there is no way to fork in two groups.

Can i done this without temporary collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB 3.4 support $facet, this means the creation of multiple space where you can compute isolated query (for example 2 type of Group).

*Provides the ability to process multiple pipelines on the input documents and outputs a document that contains the results of these pipelines*

https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/3.4-reference/#pipe._S_facet

Comment: @eri did i answer at question?